# How to calculate angle of rotation for a given line?

Tags: trigonometry

For illustration purposes, I have attached an image of the line with the angle that I want to calculate. I am trying to determine the angle of rotation and the calculation that I am using currently is as below:

angle = math.atan2(y2-y1,x2-x1)[image]

I use this formula to calculate the rotation for $A$ and $A'$, and then I add up the angle of $a$ and $b$ get the rotation. So I am really not sure if this is the correct way to do this. The idea in the end is to see if the rotation from $A$ to $A'$ is $>70$ degrees or $<70$ degrees. Sorry my math is pretty rusted at the moment.

Comment: Maybe it would be helpful to tell us first, if you fixed points and about which of the the rotation takes place.

Comment: i have fixed points in the form of x,y coordinates and the rotation is counter clockwise from point A to point A'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your formula is incorrect, assuming it's a rotation about the origin, you can find the angle of rotation using this formula:  $$ \theta = \tan^{-1}\left( \frac{y_2 x_1 - x_2 y_1}{x_1 x_2 + y_1 y_2 } \right) $$
Check this wiki page if you want to learn more about the rotational transformation:
https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rotation_%28mathematics%29

Comment: does this mean that i need to find the dot product of x and y like in the formula above?

Comment: @MugB This is based on one point: the original point has coordinates $(x_1, y_1)$ and after the transformation its coordinates are $(x_2, y_2)$.

Comment: thank you. i know where my mistake is now.